# How to use excludeDevDependencies?

Tags: serverless-framework

After read the doc: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/google/guide/packaging#development-dependencies

I made a sample to test this config.

Here is my `serverless.yml`:

```
service: exclude-development-dependencies

provider:
  name: google
  runtime: nodejs
  project: just-aloe-212502
  credentials: /Users/ldu020/workspace/nodejs-serverless-framework/.gcp/nodejs-starter-7e52b0f6fe39.json

plugins:
  - serverless-google-cloudfunctions

package:
  exclude:
    # - node_modules/**
    - .gitignore
    - .git/**
  excludeDevDependencies: true

functions:
  excludeDevDependencies:
    handler: excludeDevDependencies
    events:
      - http: path
```

The problem is `excludeDevDependencies` only works fine when I comment the `exclude` `- node_modules/**`.

It will generate `.serverless` directory and `exclude-development-dependencies.zip` include `dependency` node modules.

But for `GCP`, you don't need upload `node_modules`. You just need upload `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files to `GCP`. `GCP` will install the `node_modules` based on `package-lock.json`.

So, when should I use `excludeDevDependencies`?

Answer (score 4):

The `excludeDevDependencies` setting, is an option you can provide in the **package** config in `serverless.yml` file.

By default, it's already defined as **true**, so setting it explicitly as true won't have an impact, other than expliciting that such config is there. There would only be an impact if you setted it as *false*.

When using this feature, for example when running `serverless package` or `serverless deploy`, the CLI will follow these steps:

1. read *all* dependencies / devDependencies that are listed in your root `package.json` file
2. iterate through the dependency tree is derived by those, and find all the module/sub-module locations in the `/node_modules` folder
3. if the `include` / `exclude` paths where defined, mark those for inclusion / exclusion respectively.
4. take away the paths that are derived by the **devDependencies** derived tree, but keep those that are needed by the **dependencies** tree
5. return the resulting list of paths, which will be the **only** ones to be included in the package that will be ultimately uploaded to your Serverless provider.

For example, this makes sense for Serverless AWS Lambda environment, where you have to upload the exact sources that you need, as a whole package.

Now, since you stated that in the case of GCP the packages are handled/installed by the provider, then you shouldn't need to upload any `node_modules` paths so you should be safe by setting the entire folder in the `serverless.yml` for exclusion by using the `exclude` setting.

**Extra note:**
There were some bugs to this `excludeDevDependencies` feature in the past, that were causing it to not work correctly in some cases, but many (if not all) of them have been resolved in the latest 2.x releases.

You can find those in their [changelog](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), look for the "Packaging" feature.

If this is happening to you, consider upgrading to latest version, which is 2.25.0 as of today.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and if I used `include` of the `node_modules` then also the dev dependencies were included. After some time, I found that you just need to add `node_modules` and any folder of your interest **by not excluding them**, by using:

```
  exclude:
    - '!folderyouwanttoadd/**'
    - '!fileyouwanttoadd'
    - '!node_modules/**'
```

To include is `excludeDevDependencies: true` is optional because it is set by default. I think this is a bug of Serverless, it should work straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, no?

You dont put `node_modules` into exclude. Any dependencies you have in `package.json` should be loaded into your serverless package. Any dev-dependencies in `package.json` will be excluded if you have  `excludeDevDependencies: true`.

> GCP will install the node_modules based on package-lock.json.

I dont know what GCP is, but how do you expect it will install package.json on lmabda when there is no local file storage?

Any node_modules you need for lambda to run MUST be included in your serverless package.

Comment: https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-include-dependencies#usage-example adds it and then states "# no need to add this yourself, this plugin does it for you"